# Can you use CiviMail headers and footers on System Workflow Messages?

Tags: civimail, message-templates, system-workflow-messages, header-footer

CiviMail has an option to insert headers and footers at the top and bottom of a message (**Mailings > Headers, Footers and Automated Messages**). Is it possible to use these as a default for all "*System Workflow Messages*" Message Templates (**Mailings > Message Templates**).

The default templates are necessarily quite plain, and while I know you can edit each template individually, it would save time to be able to insert a common header/logo on all system templates. Changes to the header would apply to all templates at once, and future upgrade-related improvements to the message templates wouldn't require reverting and re-editing if all you had done was add the logo at the top.

If there is a way to do this, I am not familiar, so I realize this may be a feature request. If so, I'd appreciate tips on where this change would need to happen and could add it to my (ever-growing) rainy-day project list.

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked here:

[How can I include a custom template file in an email template using smarty?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/383/how-can-i-include-a-custom-template-file-in-an-email-template-using-smarty)

It has been answered with quite a few specific places to make the needed changes

Comment: Thanks Lobo. Just flagged this one as duplicate and I will look at your answer over there.