# Can I include a message template within a message template

Tags: civimail, smarty, pdf, message-templates

I know I can use {include } smarty function, can I also use that in message templates so we can have a generic template part that belongs to all other templates?

We want to use this for PDF templates

Comment: This is related to: http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/383/how-can-i-include-a-custom-template-file-in-an-email-template-using-smarty

Comment: That was my answer, thank you!
http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/383/how-can-i-include-a-custom-template-file-in-an-email-template-using-smarty

Comment: So did that solve your issue? Maybe you can repost the relevant solution or the link to the specific answer of the other question.